# How to turn an image into a short video with specific aspect ratio and fill empty areas with some color (black) in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, images

I'm trying to turn an image into a short video.

```
ffmpeg  -r 1/30 -i image.jpg video.mp4
```

This code does its job but the output video aspect ratio is the same as the original picture. I need to have another one – 16x10. I need the image to fit the frame without scaling/distortion and fill the empty areas with some color (e.g. black). Just exactly how it's described in the picture below. Is there any way to do it?

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7zXZ.jpg)

Update:

I've tried using the crop filter with positive values to increase the size of the frame:

```
ffmpeg -r 1/30 -i image.jpg -vf crop=in_w+200:in_h+200:0:0 -y video.mp4
```

Unfortunately, it failed. I got the error:

```
[Parsed_crop_0 @ 0x7fd8db204180] Invalid too big or non positive size for width '1280' or height '874'
[Parsed_crop_0 @ 0x7fd8db204180] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_crop_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What have you tried to get to the desired result and where did you fail? Note that superuser is a community run by volunteers, and not a free scripting service. As your question currently reads as one, it is likely to be closed as a result.

Comment: @mashuptwice I've tried using a crop filter with positive values to increase the size of the frame, but it failed. I got an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crop filter can *only* remove parts of the image, never increase its size.

You just need the [pad filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) for this.
I'm going to assume that your image has even dimensions.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/30 -i image.jpg \
  -vf "pad='if(gt(dar,16/10)\,iw\,2*trunc(ih*16/10/2))':'if(gt(dar,16/10)\,2*trunc(iw*10/16/2)\,ih)':-1:-1:color=black" \
-y video.mp4
```

Comment: Seems it works. Thank you so much! I'd never do it myself.

Comment: Once again thanks. Just asking, is it even possible to get such a kind of background effect instead of black boring color? [image with a nice background](https://i.imgur.com/3o6Eikh.png)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/43577377/